# In angular js how to create Multi dimensional array with dynamic name

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS. Here i have some doubt. I have this code:

```
.controller("boardController", function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.models = {
        selected: null,
        lists: {"A": [], "B": []} 
    };

    $http({ 
        method  : "get",
        url     : "/boards"
    })
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.ajax_val = response.data;
      angular.forEach($scope.ajax_val, function(value, key){
      var bname = value.board_name;
       $scope.models.lists.push(bname);
    });
  });
```

In this code push function returns error.. I dont know why?

Thanks Advanced!!...

Comment: **$scope.models.lists** is not an array. You can't use push method on it. You can use **$scope.models.lists.A.push()** or **$scope.models.lists.B.push()**

Comment: here i want to add dynamic names from database in lists array. and each names have one array.

Comment: Thanks Natiq... But i want to add A, B as dynamically. and add C, D, E etc.

Comment: What is **response.data** format? Can you give example data?

Comment: This is the response from laravel. [{"board_name":"boardone","id":1},{"board_name":"boardtwo","id":2}] Here i want to add these board one, board two as A, B, C....

Comment: I want result as like:  lists: {"board one": [], "board two": []}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript question, not about AngularJs itself.

But, you are getting this error because "lists" is an object and not an array, so it does not have the push function.

See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

I suggest you to change your approach to something like:

```
.controller("boardController", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.models = {
    selected: null,
    lists: [] 
};

$http({ 
    method  : "get",
    url     : "/boards"
})
.then(function(response){
  $scope.ajax_val = response.data;
  angular.forEach($scope.ajax_val, function(value, key){
    var bname = value.board_name;
    var model = {};
    model[bname] = [];
     $scope.models.lists.push(model);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. K.. Then how to create a object dynamically using my response

Comment: I'm not getting what you want exactly, but I believe if you transform your "lists" in a properly array like: lists: [] and then push an object to it like: var myObj = {}; myObj[bname] = []; $scope.models.lists.push(myObj);

Comment: You're welcome SARAN, I'll update my answer to help others with the same doubt, could you please mark as answered if it has helped you?